# Bad input shape while applying fit_transform in LDA

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, lda

I have applied `get_dummies()` method on my dataset after that splitting the dataset for training and testing purpose when I tried to apply LDA's `fit_transform()` method it outputs:

> ValueError: bad input shape (26905, 8)

What am I doing wrong? I am not sure if the problem is due to `get_dummies()` method or is it anything else that I am missing

```
# Sample Code


df = pd.read_csv('/Users/rushirajparmar/Downloads/Problem 16 (1)/Problem 16/Problem 16/train_file.csv')


df.drop(['UsageClass','CheckoutType','CheckoutYear','CheckoutMonth'],axis = 1,inplace = True)


Y=pd.get_dummies(df,columns = ['MaterialType'])
X=pd.get_dummies(df,columns = ['Title','Creator','Subjects','Publisher','PublicationYear'])


X.drop(['MaterialType'],axis = 1,inplace = True)


Y.drop(['ID','Checkouts','Title','Creator','Subjects','Publisher','PublicationYear'],axis = 1,inplace = True)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.15)


from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)


from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA
lda = LDA(n_components = 1)
X_train = lda.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
X_test = lda.transform(X_test)
```

## Dataset:

Here is the [train_file.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9lg83lj7zumdunj/train_file.csv?dl=0) for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not have to apply the get_dummies on target variables. You can directly feed the multi-class labels to `LDA`.

**[From Documentation:](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html#sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.fit_transform)**

> **fit_transform(X, y=None, **fit_params)**
>
> Fit to data, then
>   transform it.
>
> Fits transformer to X and y with optional parameters fit_params and
>   returns a transformed version of X.
>
> **Parameters:**
>   **X :** numpy array of shape [n_samples, n_features] Training
>   set.
>
> **y :** numpy array of shape [n_samples] Target values.
>
> Returns:   X_new : numpy array of shape [n_samples, n_features_new]
>   Transformed array.

Hence, your `y` has to be one dimensional.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, df['MaterialType'], test_size = 0.15)

lda = LDA(n_components = 1)
X_train = lda.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Minot fix - not just `lda.fit_transform(X_train, df['MaterialType'])`, you should do `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, df['MaterialType'], test_size = 0.15)` to get correct number of samples. After all, there's possibly `MemoryError` because of enormous shape of `X`

Comment: @AI_Learning Thanks for the explanation! I am sure this was the mistake that I was making but anyway I couldn't run it either on my PC or by using GPU on Google Colab, I get memory error and my session crashes.

Comment: @AI_Learning is there any possibility for further optimization so that I can run this code without getting memory error?

Comment: I would suggest asking this as seperate question, with more details on number of columns, rows, number of categories in each variables, etc.